# How to find what caused an event? VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I have a Handler for a ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged event. The 'sender' tells me that it is the ComboBox that caused the event, and what its text and value currently is, but what I need to find out is what caused the ComboBox to change its selection in the first place?

How do I find out which line in my program is causing the ComboBox to change, please?

Comment: You could initialize an instance of the [`StackTrace` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace) and use a loop to iterate the frames.

Comment: That sounds right, but I am not sure how to use that example in my case. Do you know of a working VB.Net example that demonstrates how this is done?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. And I am currently not in a position to do it myself. However there isn't that much to it. All you need to do is to create a new `StackTrace` (`Dim st As New StackTrace(True)`), then iterate the frames either in a `For` loop using [`FrameCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.framecount), or in a `For Each` loop over [`GetFrames()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframes).

Comment: On the other hand if this is merely for debugging purposes you can also use [`Environment.StackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.stacktrace).

Comment: I managed to create a small example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WIZGIb) which contains three different methods showing how you can iterate and use the `StackFrame`s: `PrintStackTrace()`, `PrintFullStackTrace()` and `PrintDefaultStackTrace()`. -- May I ask what you need this for? Do you need to programmatically determine what triggered the change, or are you just using this for debugging?

Comment: That is an excellent example and will be of use to anyone looking at this thread!!

Comment: Glad I could help, but does it solve your problem? What are you actually using this for? Does your code need to know what caused the selection to change, or is it just for troubleshooting?

Comment: I am not sure - it will take a while to work through all the results, but I have a feeling that the ComboBox datasource is causing the change:
CountyHuntingMapper.Main.SearchComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged()                                    
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged()
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex()
System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.DataManager_PositionChanged()
System.EventHandler.Invoke()
System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnPositionChanged()
System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState()
etc.

Comment: Yes I was trying to find what caused the change, as it is an annoying one-off occurrence when the program starts.

Comment: If you don't want it to happen when the program starts then Gabriel's answer should be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I added the following code to my Handler, and found some useful clues:

```
    Dim st As New StackTrace(True)
    For i As Integer = 0 To st.FrameCount - 1
        Dim sf As StackFrame = st.GetFrame(i)
        Debug.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Line: " & _
        sf.GetFileLineNumber().ToString & _
        "  Method: " & sf.GetMethod().ToString)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the SelectionChangeCommitted event and not the SelectedIndexChanged event.

The SelectionChangeCommitted event works similar to SelectedIndexChanged event, the only difference is that the SelectedIndexChanged event gets fired when the ComboBox selection is changed from code i.e. during DataBinding or when the form is loaded.

So, if you populate your ComboBox in any place in your code, that should be the place where the event is triggered.

Comment: No, that did not catch the problem.